# problem with changing colour of a textbox

Tags: javascript

*I want the background colour of a text box to change to lightgreen when the textbox gets focus and its background colour to revert to white when it loses focus. My code works perfectly on localhost and when the browser is Safari.

However, with all the other browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera ) nothing happens. I'm doing something stupid, but what?!

```
<script>
   function test(id)
{
  var ctrl_name = id;   
  document.getElementById('Name').value = ctrl_name;            
}    
 </script>

 <body>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery    
        /1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){    

 $('.clickOnMe').blur(function(){          
 $(this).css('background', 'white' );
   });      
   $('.clickOnMe').mousedown(function(){          
       $(this).css( 'background', 'lightgreen');
   });
});
</script>
```

and in the textboxes -

```
onclick="test(this.id)"  class="clickOnMe"
```

No error messages/ Simply won't work except on localhost and Safari.*

Answer (score 2):

#### CSS only

This can be done with `css` without javascript. Example:

```css
.custom-textarea:focus { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<textarea class="custom-textarea">Click on me</textarea>
```

---

#### JS with jQuery

If you would like to use `js` and `jQuery` anyway:
You can use `.focus()` event instead of `.mousedown()`.

> - This method is a shortcut for `.on( "focus", handler )` in the first and second variations, and `.trigger( "focus" )` in the third.
> - The `focus` event is sent to an element when it gains focus.
> - Source: [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Example:

```js
$('textarea').focus(function() { 
    $(this).css("background-color","lightgreen"); 
});
$('textarea').blur(function() { 
    $(this).css("background-color","white"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<textarea class="custom-textarea">Click on me</textarea>
```

Or in ES6

```js
$('textarea').focus((e) => $(e.currentTarget).css("background-color","lightgreen"));
$('textarea').blur((e) => $(e.currentTarget).css("background-color","white"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<textarea class="custom-textarea">Click on me</textarea>
```